# Multiple draggabble Images on Canvas-surface Famo.us/Angular?

Tags: famous-angular

We are trying to create a canvas-surface with famous/angular, that can contains multiple image.

The images that are added should be movable, and support all transformation (Rotation,scaling & skew) on dynamically mouse move or button click.

Can any one help us how to create the canvas-surface or any Documentation that explains usage of famous canvas-surface

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need canvas for this. Simply create surfaces with an  inside or use *fa-image-surface*. Use the built in event directives or create a *GenericSync* for each Surface that can fire off a Transitionable or Transform, Rotate, and Skew the surface to taste. There is a fa-canvas-surface but it doesn't sound like it is need for this solution. There is also *fa-draggable* but it is really new, so good luck.